# Strange efficiency of std::list.sort()

Tags: c++, list, sorting, stl, linked-list

Ok, so the following:

I want to use a double linked list and want to sort the objects within it. The objects are of another class. The strange thing is: When I use a double linked list I created myself, I sort the elements in the moment when I add them to the list. This is like Insertion Sort, so with efficiency n^2.

But this is way faster, than using the std::list ordering, in which I add all elements to the list and call sort() after that. And I really dont get why....

For further information: in the moment I sort ~ 500 elements.

Am I doing something wrong with the lists ?

Edit: some code

code for the std::list

```
for every object:
    list.push_back(object);
list.sort();
```

my list:

```
struct node{
    someObject* data;
    float depth;
    node* prev;
    node* next;
    node(someObject* o){
        data = o;
        prev = NULL;
        next = NULL;
        depth = depthFunc(o);
    }
    float depthFunc(someObject* o);
};
struct myList{
    node* head;
    node* tail;
    void insertAfter(node* toAdd, node* n);
    void insertBefore(node* toAdd, node* n);
    void addNode(someObject* o){
        node* n = new node(o);
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        } else {
            node* temp = head;
            while(temp != NULL && temp->depth < n->depth){
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            if (temp != NULL) insertBefore(n, temp);
            else insertAfter(n, tail);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I guess your n^2 is the worst case complexity, if you are lucky, depending on the data (presorted) it can be better

Comment: How are you measuring this?

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: And inserting list elements as they are being generated has `O(N log N)` comparisons because `std::binary_search` on bidirectional iterators does `O(log N)` comparisons (you still have `O(N^2)` iterator increments, but they are typically a lot less expensive than comparisons). The `std::list::sort` is likewise of `O(N log N)` complexity (comparison counting). So unless you provide us with more code, we can only guess to what explains your results.

Comment: added some simple code

Comment: we need complete, but minimalistic code which reproduces the behaviour.

Comment: I would guess that it is that your container uses pointers where `std::list` does not. See http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#slow-containers

Answer (score 2):

Your hand written sort function has O(`N^2`) time complexity. Each element is inserted (you call `addNode` `n` times), and you require `n` operations to find the insertion point (giving `n * n = n^2`).

`std::list<T>::sort()` is required to have O(`n lg n`) complexity, which is much faster than O(`N^2`). (`lg n` grows much more slowly than `n`)

Your hand written sort is a variant of [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Note that for most inputs, using `std::vector` and `std::sort` instead of `std::list` and `std::list::sort` will give faster results.

---

If your question is asking "Why is the handwritten version faster?", that depends on your input. Insertion sort can be `O(n)` for some inputs. (For your implementation, that happens when the elements are inserted in reverse order)

Comment: OP: "But this is way faster, than using the std::list ordering, in which I add all elements to the list and call sort() after that. And I really dont get why.... "

Comment: @DyP: Hmm.. I see your point. The question is a bit confusing as to whether it says that the `std::list` version was faster (i.e. "Why isn't my handwritten code faster?") or the handwritten version is faster (i.e. "Why is the handwritten version faster?")